# How to access XS server of multitenant database with same host name and system number

Tags: database, hana, hana-xs

Tenant HANA database installed in same host.

All tenant database has same host name and system number i.e. `00`.
To access XS server we follow link `http:/<hostname>:80<instance>` since for all tenant we have same host name and system number.

How can we access XS server of tenant database?

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the individual tenants you need to modify the configuration settings. This pertains to the [xsc](/questions/tagged/xsc) engine.

Each tenant has to be enabled and you need to modify your local hosts file or DNS entries for them.

In the following [link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.02/en-US/2fb0d4e5bcf249d9a86e74ffb0a04f6e.html) you can see the step by step guide to doing it.

Essentianly though the settings in the xsengine.ini for "public_urls" is the key area there you can set additional tenants. You can get to those via [saphanastudio](/questions/tagged/saphanastudio) or via the SQL console or [tag: hdbsql] command.

```
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('xsengine.ini', 'database', 'HXE')
SET ('public_urls', 'http_url') = 'http://hxe.mysystem.com:8090' 
WITH RECONFIGURE;
```

Once you have each of your tenants set and a public url set you can either do DNS entries if you have access to do so or you can set it in your local hosts file. This giving a unique URL to each tenant you have created on the system. The same goes for the "https_url" if you have https enabled.

```
ALTER SYSTEM ALTER CONFIGURATION ('xsengine.ini', 'database', 'HXE')
SET ('public_urls', 'https_url') = 'https://hxe.mysystem.com:8090' 
WITH RECONFIGURE;
```